# Changing the AJAX url in Jquery Plguin, JQGrid?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I'm using the jqgrid plugin for jquery and jquery ui and I would like to change the AJAX url on a dom event. 
this is the instatiation of the jqgrid table:

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'AJAX/JSON/json_member_mail.aspx',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['','Title', 'from','message',''], 
colModel :[ 
      {name:'checkbox', index:'pms.pm_id', width:15, gridstate:'hidden',sortable:false} ,
      {name:'title', index:'pmthreads.pmthread_subject', width:140}, 
      {name:'from', index:'pms.pm_authoruser_id', width:110, align:'center',classes:'mofo_id' } ,
      {name:'message', index:'message', width:445, sortable:false},
      {name:'tasks', index:'tasks', sortable:false, width:65, align:'right'} 
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:20,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    width: '100%',
    height: '800',
    sortable:true,
    sortname: 'someting that makes sense to the cragted mysql query ',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'Mail'
  });
```

now this page shows the  user mail inbox in my program... now I would like to change the url to member_mail_sent to show the outbox but then I would also need to change colName and colModel, sortname etc...

I remember seeing something that made this alot easier in the documentation but now I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

found it,
yeap victor is right though I didn't check back early enough to get your hint but I did it with setGridParam...

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"AJAX/JSON/json_member_mail_sent.aspx?message_mask="+message_mask,page:1}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Answer (score 4):

You would use the [`setGridParam`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method to change the `url` option.